# How to copy data from multiple source workbooks within a folder to another workbook thereafter saving as a new workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy a specific row from a worksheet and paste it into another workbook sheet. Thereafter saving the file as a new workbook.

This will need to be done on many workbooks in a folder. For each source workbook copy the row of data, paste it in the master workbook and save the workbook as a new workbook. I require 10 master workbooks as there are 10 source workbooks.

This is where my workbooks reside.
[image]

This is a sample of a source workbook file.
[image]

I need to copy the data without headers, so row 2. This needs to be done for all files within the folder above. All files have the same layout with just row 2 where the data resides.

The master/destination workbook
[image]

The data should be pasted in row 9. This templated workbook resides in a different folder.

Current code increments the rows. I need a new master workbook for each source workbook and thereafter save the master workbook with a source workbook name as a suffix Example "Master workbook-AAAA".xlsx

```vb
Option Explicit
Const FOLDER_PATH = "C:\Users\\Desktop\Split Files\"  'REMEMBER END BACKSLASH' 

Sub ImportWorksheets()    
    'Process all Excel files in specified folder'     
    Dim sFile As String  'file to process   
    Dim wsTarget As Worksheet    
    Dim wbSource As Workbook    
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet  
    Dim rowTarget As Long         'output row

    rowTarget = 9

    'check the folder exists    
    If Not FileFolderExists(FOLDER_PATH) Then
    MsgBox "Specified folder does not exist, exiting!"
    Exit Sub   
    End If

    'reset application settings in event of error'    
    On Error GoTo errHandler    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'set up the target worksheet'    
    Set wsTarget = Sheets("DATABASE")

    'loop through the Excel files in the folder'    
    sFile = Dir(FOLDER_PATH & "*.xls*")    
    Do Until sFile = ""

        'open the source file and set the source worksheet - ASSUMED WORKSHEET(1)
        Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(FOLDER_PATH & sFile)
        Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets(1)

        'import the data'
        With wsTarget
            .Range("A" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("A2").Value
            .Range("B" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("B2").Value
            .Range("C" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("C2").Value
            .Range("D" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("D2").Value
            .Range("E" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("E2").Value
            .Range("F" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("F2").Value
            .Range("G" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("G2").Value
            .Range("H" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("H2").Value
            .Range("I" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("I2").Value
        End With

        'close the source workbook, increment the output row and get the next file'
        wbSource.Close SaveChanges:=False
        rowTarget = rowTarget + 1
        sFile = Dir()    
    Loop

errHandler:    
    On Error Resume Next   
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    'tidy up'    
    Set wsSource = Nothing    
    Set wbSource = Nothing     
    Set wsTarget = Nothing 
End Sub 

Private Function FileFolderExists(strPath As String) As Boolean
    If Not Dir(strPath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then FileFolderExists = True 
End Function
```

The result is shown below
[image]

Update.

I tried a different approach, however the workbook is crashing.

[image]

Comment: You need to 
(1) list all the workbooks in a folder, 
(2) open a workbook, 
(3) find a particular worksheet in a workbook, 
(4) find a particular row in a worksheet, 
(5) copy a row from one worksheet to a worksheet in another workbook, 
(6) save the other workbook. 
Which piece are you having problems with?

Comment: Hi Nicholas. Im having problems with (5) and (6). So currently i can save data from row 2 for all the source workbooks thats located in a folder to the master workbook row 9. But thats not the solution i need as the code i have increments it in 1 master workbook. The solution i need is to create a loop that will copy row 2 from the source workbook and paste it in row 9 of the master workbook thereafter saving it as a new workbook x 10 as there are 10 source workbooks.

Comment: I assume you want to create the new master workbooks from the template, correct ? Where are the new workbooks to be saved to ?

Comment: Hi there. Yes i want to create the new master workbooks from the template. The new workbooks need to be saved in a new folder on my desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```vb
 'open template
    Const MASTER = "path-to-file\master.xlsx"
    Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open(MASTER)
    Set wsTarget = wbTarget.Sheets(1)
    wsTarget.Unprotect "password"

    Do While sFile <> ""

        ' read source
        Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(sFolder & sFile, 1, 1) ' update links, readonly
        Set wsSource = wbSource.Sheets(1)

        ' create target
        wsTarget.Name = "DATABASE"
        wsTarget.Range("A" & ROW_TARGET).Resize(1, 9) = wsSource.Range("A2:I2").Value2
        wbTarget.SaveAs "path\to\Master_" & sFile
        wbSource.Close False
    
        sFile = Dir

    Loop
    wsTarget.protect "password"
    wbTarget.Close False
```

Comment: Hi there. I will try it out and feedback soon. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi There. I tried this approach, however I'm not sure if I made the change correctly. Please kindly see screenshot of the amendments.

Comment: @coder Add a `\\` to the end of FOLDER_PATH value.

Comment: Hi @CDP1802 I added the '\' to the end of the FOLDER_PATH value. its just opening up the Master template workbook but not saving any new files to the location or anything.

Comment: @coder The 2 lines under read source are wrong. MASTER should be FOLDER_PATH and sheets(DATABASE) should be as I have, assuming it is the first sheet you want to copy from.

Comment: Wow thanks @CDP1802. It worked !!! :) .. Really appreciate your time for helping me.

Comment: Hi @CDP1802. I just noticed a small issue. Under 'Read source' we are copying the first sheet which is correct Set wsSource = wbSource.Sheets(1). However can you tell me how can i ensure that the sheet name remains as 'DATABASE' because now its naming the sheet as the file name example AAAA

Comment: Perfect !! Thank you so much

Comment: Hi @CDP1802 I'm not sure if this should be posted as another question but its dealing with do while loop that we created. The DATABASE sheet is now password protected and i receive a error when i try to copy to it. I tried this code under the 'create target' section of the loop...wsTarget("DATABASE").Unprotect Password:="2021" and then after the "Save as" part i want to re-enable the password so that in the individual sheets the password is enabled which wsTarget("DATABASE").Protect Password:="2021". Any idea what am i doing wrong ? Thanks

Comment: @code I updated code. `wsTarget` is the DATABASE worksheet so just add `wsTarget.Unprotect "password"` before the loop. Protect again before closing. Actually as you are not saving changes then the protect is redundant.

Comment: You are Brilliant. Thank you so much bud.